# I need to get the date offset by deleting the Calendar and using LocalDateTime

Tags: java

I need to get the date offset by deleting the Calendar and using LocalDateTime

```
public static LocalDateTime obtenerDesplazamientoFecha(LocalDateTime fechaDesde,
        int tipoDesplazamiento, int desplazamineto) {

    if (fechaDesde != null) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(fechaDesde);
        cal.add(tipoDesplazamiento, desplazamineto);
        if (Calendar.MONTH == tipoDesplazamiento) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        }
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what output you expect - can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: The method is using `Calendar` fields in `tipoDesplazamiento`. Shouldn't that be changed?

Comment: I don’t quite know what you are asking for. Also, please use English on this platform exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

The counterpart of [`Calendar.add(int field, int amount)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add-int-int-) is [`LocalDateTime.plus(long amountToAdd, TemporalUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-), but it needs a [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) instead of `int`.

The easiest way would be to adjust the parameters:

```
public static LocalDateTime obtenerDesplazamientoFecha(LocalDateTime dateTime, 
            TemporalUnit unit, long amountToAdd) {
    if (dateTime != null) {
        dateTime = dateTime.plus(amountToAdd, unit);
        if(ChronoUnit.MONTHS == unit) {
            dateTime= dateTime.minusDays(1l);
        }
    }
    return dateTime;
}
```

But when you need to keep the method signature you need to map the "Calendar-Fields" like `Calendar.MONTH` to a `TemporalUnit`. e.g:

```
public static TemporalUnit map(int calendarField) {
    switch(calendarField) {
    case Calendar.YEAR:
        return ChronoUnit.YEARS;
    case Calendar.MONTH:
        return ChronoUnit.MONTHS;
    case Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH:
    case Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR:
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS;
    // add all the other "Fields" which needs to be mapped
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported calendarField: "+calendarField);
    }
}
```